# Electron scattering from Coulomb potential in canonical formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering

[image]

I am trying to follow Zee's computation of the amplitude for the pictured process.  I have already done it using the Feynman rules for writing amplitudes and now I am confirming the result in the canonical formalism which gives

\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{M}=\big\langle P\big|e^{-i H T}\big|p\big\rangle~~.
\end{equation*}

The interaction part of the Lagrangian is

\begin{align*}
 \mathcal{L}&=eA_\mu\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi~~.
\end{align*}

To derive the Hamiltonian from the Lagrangian we compute the conjugate momentum of $\psi$ as

\begin{equation*}
 \pi=\cfrac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\dot\psi}=\cfrac{\delta}{\delta\dot\psi}\big(eA_\mu\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi\big)=0~~.
\end{equation*}

The Hamiltonian density, then, is

\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{H}=\pi\dot\psi-\mathcal{L}=-\mathcal{L}~~,
\end{equation*}

and the Hamiltonian is

\begin{equation*}
 H=\int\!d^3x\,\mathcal{H}=-\int\!d^3x\,\mathcal{L}~~,
\end{equation*}

so we obtain

\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{M}=\big\langle P\big|e^{-i H T}\big|p\big\rangle=\big\langle P\big|\exp\!\left\{  i\!\int\!d^3x\,eA_\mu\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi\int\!dx^0 \right\}\big|p\big\rangle~~,
\end{equation*}

Now I assume that $\psi(x)$ does not depend on time because it is a constant on the leg in to the interaction and also a constant on the way out.  This allows me to combine the integrals into $\int d^4x$.  Taylor expansion to leading order gives

\begin{align*}
 \mathcal{M}&=\big\langle P\big|1+ ie\int\!d^4x\,A_\mu\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi  \big|p\big\rangle\\[4pt]
 &=\big\langle P\big|p\big\rangle+ie\int\!d^4x\,\big\langle P\big| A_\mu\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi  \big|p\big\rangle~~.
\end{align*}

Zee seems to indicate that the first term disappears.  Since momentum states are Dirac orthogonal, the first term appears to me to be

$$ \big\langle P\big|p\big\rangle=(2\pi)^4\delta(P-p) ~~, $$

so I do not immediately see why this term disappears.

Comment: You're essentially asking why $P \ne p$, right?

Comment: I believe $P\neq p$ due to the interaction with the Coulomb potential.  Even if $P$ was equal to $p$, that term would not vanish and would be weird to normalize for the probability interpretation.

Comment: I mean, if $P \ne p$, wouldn't the delta function be zero?

Comment: I think $\int\!dp\,\delta(p-P)=0$ if $P$ is not within the the bounds of integration but I do not think $p\neq P\implies\delta(p-P)=0$.  If it we had this implication, then momentum eigenstates would be orthogonal but they are not orthogonal.  Sometimes, when normalized, they are called "Dirac orthonormal" but the set of things which are Dirac orthonormal is subset of things which are *not* orthonormal at all.  So it would be a contradiction to assign the properties of orthonormal kets to kets which are known not to be that.